# Flask server gets expired whenever I switch from flask page to react in another directory, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, flask

I place flask file and react file in different directories, whenever I switch from flask to React in VS code, the flask server gets expires, thus I can not pass user input values from react to flask server. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I put the flask page in the same project as react page, so I don't need to switch in VS code